# Windbg gets stuck after attaching debugger

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

Trying to debug a 32bit, .net 4.5, winforms application, using the largeadressaware flag on Windows Server 2008R2 gets stuck after attaching windbg (latest version) to the process.
Seems like after each keystroke hangs for a long time and the whole os becomes non-responsive.

Wierd thing is it only happens on our DEV environment, while on TEST environment seems to work fine (same OS).

What could cause this?

Comment: You mean it displays `BUSY` immediately when you type or when you enter any command? If it is a command what commands are you using? Some things to note, once attached it does a lazy loading of symbols and will moan if the pdbs don't match, this is normally fine and shouldn't affect debugging. What really kills it is if you have specified or previously opened any source files in your workspace, WinDbg unless it has previously verified that the source matches the dlls will try to verify and find source files for the entire current call stack, in which case try with a blank workspace

Comment: The above is made worse if resources reside on a network, I assume you are using the 32-bit version of WinDbg to debug your 32-bit app? You can use 64-bit version but must switch the bitness using `.effmach` command

Comment: @EdChum The command I'm trying to enter is just ".loadby sos clr".
Is there anything I can do to prevent it from trying to access the source files (even though I don't remember trying to open any source files).

Comment: If you have never opened or specified the source files then WinDbg will not try to open or resolve them. Have you tried `.load` command instead? You will need to specify the path if you use `.load`, `.loadby` is a convenience method so you don't specify the path. It's possible this is the problem as it has to try to find the dll. See this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563964(v=vs.85).aspx) link